# Select random subset for n groups in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I have a MySQL table `players` and I'm trying to randomly put all players in n groups (n>=2) where each group has a determined but variable size.

Example time:

Put the 10.000 rows from the table `players` into 3 groups where group A contains 5.000 players, group B contains 3.000 players and group C contains 2.000 players.

Another example could be:

Put the 10.000 rows from the table `players` into 4 groups where group A contains 3.000 players, group B contains 3.000 players and group C contains 2.000 players and group D contains 2.000 players.

Now my questions:
Should I do this in PHP or MySQL? (I was thinking that MySQL would be faster probably)
Is there a better (more efficient) way to do this in MySQL than to generate random numbers for each row and order the rows by that and then use a OFFSET and LIMIT to select the rows?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient and simple way of doing this would be to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM players
ORDER BY rand()
```

And then iterate over the results in a couple of PHP FOR loops (one for each group).

This way, you'll be only running one query and also iterating over the results once (which is something you actually have to do anyways).

Comment: It does. But the query you can come around to make a similar behaviour might take even more. Check this [link](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/). Take into account that you don't want to get just random rows, but rather random rows not previously selected. That means you'll have to also keep track of that and I believe that will take longer than the rand(). But you should try both approaches and see which one performs better (and report back, as I'm also intrigued :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL.  The strategy is as follows.  Randomize the rows and enumerate them.  Then calculate the breaks in the enumeration for each group.

```
select t.*,
       (case when (seqnum - 1) / totalcnt < 0.3 then 'GroupA'
             when (seqnum - 1) / totalcnt < 0.6 then 'GroupB'
             when (seqnum - 1) / totalcnt < 0.8 then 'GroupC'
             else 'GroupD'
        end) as WhichGroup
from (select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 as seqnum, totalcnt
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, count(*) as totalcnt from t) const
      order by rand()
     ) t;
```

The `order by rand()` does slow things down.  However, getting random samples is not an inherently fast process.

A faster way -- which creates slightly different sized groups from what you are looking for -- is to do the following:

```
select t.*,
       (case when rand() < 0.3 then 'GroupA'
             when rand() < 0.6 then 'GroupB'
             when rand() < 0.8 then 'GroupC'
             else 'GroupD'
        end) as WhichGroup
from t;
```